# How to change orientation in ionic without redirecting?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, screen-orientation

I have application based on cordova and ionic, written in typescript.
I have to create single view to be able to change from "portrait" to "landscape",
without redirecting.

Here is what I do...

```
        $scope.$on("orientation:changed",(event: ng.IAngularEvent) => {
            var orientation: number = (<any>window).orientation;
            if (orientation === 90 || orientation === -90) { // Landscape
                this.$stateService.transitionTo("app.timesheet-landscape");
            } else if (orientation === 0 || orientation === 180 || orientation === -180) { // Portrait
                this.$stateService.transitionTo("app.timesheet-portrait");
            }
        });
```

What is wrong with that?

Ok... I'm actually need to create a new "ui-route-state", this is not maintainable. The transition is not smooth.

Please can any one help please?

If it would be possible to lock every other views to "portrait" and to control only one it would be great.

BTW: Does Android or iOS have a difference between these two?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Consider using [this plugin](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) to lock/set the rotation dynamically on Android/iOS

Comment: Ohhh I don't have a problem to know what orientation I am. I have a problem to notify ui-router to refresh a view.